# enlarge bmp file by n scale

Tags: file, bmp

All right guys, I'm working on a method to enlarge a bmp file, but i am a little confused on how to go about it. This is how I think the enlarge would go:

Let's say we have the bmp file:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

a 3x2 2D array, so let's say we want to enlarge this image by a scale of 2, then the new image would look like this:

```
0 0 1 1 2 2
0 0 1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4 5 5
3 3 4 4 5 5
```

I am correct about this or does it work in a different way?
Thank you, I just need to understand how it works to be able to write down an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically call this image resize method: "brute sizing" or "image scaling"

1. **size calculation:**

   *Original image size:* 3 x 2 pixels *(total of 6 pixels)*

   > if you scale the height by 2 and the width by 2

   *Final image size:* 6 x 4 pixels *(total of 24 pixels)*
2. **Implementation:**

   here is an example:
   lets say:  **AA**=3, **AB**=2, **AC**=6 *and* **BA**=6, **BB**=4, **BC**=24 *and* **scaleX**=2, **scaleY**=2

---

```
    int ptotal = AC; //or = AA * AB

    for (pcount = 0; pcount < ptotal; ++pcount)
    {
        img_x = (pcount%(AA))*scaleX;
        if ((pcount%(scaleX))==0)
            img_y += scaleY;
        set_rect_BMP(bmp,img_x,img_y,scaleX,scaleY,r,g,b);
    }
```

---

```
int set_rect_BMP(BMP* bmp, int x, int y, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b) {

    int i, j;
    for (i = y; i < h+y; ++i)
    {
        for (j = x; j < w+x; ++j)
        {
            BMP_SetPixelRGB( bmp, j, i, r, g, b );
            //BMP_SetPixelRGB( bmp, the x coord, the y coord, red, green, blue );
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Diagram of the algorithm:**

[image]

---

further explanation will be given if needed ;)
see more on wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling